# Can MongoDB Update Aggregation Pipeline conditionally replace the document?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given a document like;

```json
{
  "name": "Jason",
  "foo": "bar",
  "version": 3,
  // ...
}
```

Is it possible to specify an update aggregation pipeline to conditionally update the entire document based on a property of the current document? i.e. to specify something like;

```js
const newDocument = { ...currentDocument, version: 4, foo: "baz" };

if (document.version == 3) 
  $replaceRoot(newDocument)
else
  doNothing()
```

---

### Post answer edit

The marked answer below does address this question. For the sake of being thorough I would like to add some context as to why this question was asked as the answer will slightly change.

CosmosDB provides the feature of [Optimistic Concurrency Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency#optimistic-concurrency-control) (OCC) that allows CosmosDB to reject a command on a document if the document has changed unexpectedly. Important to note that the client can supply the expected version (`_etag` property) of the document.

MongoDB does use this feature under the hood, but does not expose OCC to the client. This means that your entire document change needs to be described in the Mongo Update pipeline syntax. This syntax is okay for simple documents and update commands. But, it is not a replacement for testable business logic code.

To expose OCC to the client when using MongoDB use a `version` property or similar and ensure to target the expected version in the command filter as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70726840/can-mongodb-update-aggregation-pipeline-conditionally-replace-the-document#comment125049989_70727808).

Comment: Is this for one document or many that could match the selection criteria ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can, you can build the update pipeline in code like you did but you can also do it in Mongo with `$cond` like so:

```
db.collection.updateOne({},
[
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$version",
              3
            ]
          },
          {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$ROOT",
              {
                version: 4,
                foo: "baz"
              }
            ]
          },
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AU8DC9LGJtj)

Comment: I see, so `newRoot` will evaluate to a document regardless of whether the condition of `document.version == 3` is met or not. `$cond` is a ternary and both true and false paths will evaluate a document. Is it possible to reject this update command if `document.version != 3`? So only update if `document.version == 3`, otherwise return some error response?

Comment: Is the same outcome achieved by simply using `version` in the filter - `db.collection.update({ _id: doc_id, version: expectedVersion}, {...})`?

Comment: yes, i showed how to use a conditional update as this was the question, but if you only need to update under once scenario then you could use that as the query.